# log4cplus::SocketAppender error when attempting to log a buffer with more than 8000 characters

Tags: logging, log4cplus

I am attempting to log message via `log4cplus::SocketAppender`. These messages are serialized using google protobuf.
I have no problem sending logs with small size. However, if I attempt to log messages with character length greater than 8000, I get following error message:

> log4cplus:ERROR SocketBuffer::appendString()- Attempt to write beyond end of buffer

My current workaround is breaking these buffers into smaller chunks before sending it across the network.

Here is a snippet of my property file (named test.properties):

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=TRACE
log4cplus.logger.loglogger  = TRACE,SocketAppender

log4cplus.appender.SocketAppender = log4cplus::SocketAppender
log4cplus.appender.SocketAppender.host=127.0.0.1
log4cplus.appender.SocketAppender.port = 5555
log4cplus.appender.SocketAppender.serverName = simpleserver
```

Here is a snippet of my sender code:

```
 int main()
{           
    log4cplus::initialize();
    LogLog::getLogLog()->setInternalDebugging(true);
    {
        ConfigureAndWatchThread* configureThread = new ConfigureAndWatchThread(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("test.properties"), 1000);
        
        root = Logger::getRoot();
        loglogger = Logger::getInstance("loglogger");
        loglogger.setLogLevel(ALL_LOG_LEVEL);
        unsigned char Mybuffer[10000];
        
        //populating and serializing code for Mybuffer 
        
        LOG4CPLUS_INFO(loglogger,Mybuffer);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Question:

1. Is it something that I am missing in the property file which is causing this issue?
2. Is there a way to increase this socket buffer size so that I can send buffers with more than 8000 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `MyBuffer` is binary data then you are using log4cplus wrong. It is meant to log text strings, not binary data.

Also, there is a limit to the length of a buffer to `8*1024` bytes. See `socketappender.h`.

Comment: `MyBuffer` is of type `unsigned char` . `uint8_t` is a typedef for it. Apologies for confusing you. Edited my code accordingly. Also, since this is not an issue but something by design, I will accept this as answer

Comment: On the side note, are you the actual developer/ contributor for log4cplus? I believe I have seen your multiple answers earlier related to log4cplus on this forum (those were also very helpful, if I may add!!!).